# Different Swaggers UI? How to show Autorize button?

Tags: swagger-ui

I have used http://editor.swagger.io to produce swagger.yaml for my web.api application (node js). But I was confused when I saw the swagger with my methods. Button Authorize was hidden. But in editor it was shown and works.
The Difference is so:

1. In Editor everything is all right: 
   [image]
2. But when I insert same swagger.yaml in my application, Launch browser then I saw the diffrerent view:
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a very old version of Swagger UI (2.0?), whereas the Swagger Editor uses UI 3.x.

In UI 2.x, you can enter the API key in the text box in the header:

[image: API keys in Swagger UI 2.x]

Note that UI 2.x is no longer maintained by developers. Consider using the latest version of Swagger UI instead.

Comment: Yes It helps. I have investigated code. And it occurs that npm module swagger-toools has dependency swagger-ui (2.x). So I installed npm swagger-ui-express (3.x). And replace code that includes as middlware native ui to fresh installed version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Unfornulately I don't remember the exact solution.
But I remember, it had something todo with a bug (in swaggerui) and security-definitions (**type=basic must be present to show the button or something...**).

This is from my swagger.json (and Auth-Button is shown):

```
<!-- snip -->

"/xx/xxx/xxx" : {
   "post" : {
      "responses" : {... },
      "security" : [ {
         "demouser" : [ ]
      }, {
         "api_key" : [ ]
      } ]
   }
 }

<!-- snip -->

"securityDefinitions" : {
   "api_key" : {
      "type" : "apiKey",
      "name" : "api_key",
      "in" : "header"
   },
   "demouser" : {
      "type" : "basic"
   }
}
```

**Edit Info:**
You should also take a look at OpenAPI (swagger 3.0?!). It has much cleaner Specification and API! (swaggerui also supports OpenAPI/Swagger3!)